# Is it possible to make a form for a browser, store data local and sent data when browser gets online?

Tags: jquery

I wanted to make a form, with 3 checkboxes, these have values. When the form gets submitted and the browser is offline. The form data has to be sent when the browser/device gets online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Service Worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) if you rely on HTTPS,
or you could check for [navigator.onLine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine)

## Submit form data using `navigator.onLine` and `online` event

- **Use AJAX** to send data to the server.
- Create a **pre-submit stage** where you check if the [navigator is onLine *MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/Online_and_offline_events).
- On pre-submit, **if online - submit** the form data
- On pre-submit, **if offline - push** your form data object to the `stack` array.
- Listen for `online` event and [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics))-empty the `stack` Array, submitting objects one by one.

```js
 // App's stack to store form data - while offline
const stack = []; // Make available throughout your APP. Or use sessionStorage

// SUBMIT
function submit(formData) {
   console.log(formData); // TODO: send to server using jQuery $.ajax or whatever
}

// PRE SUBMIT
function preSubmit(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submit, we'll use AJAX

  const formData = { // or use JS's FormData API instead
     action: this.action, method: this.method, data: $(this).serialize()
  };

  if (navigator.onLine) {
    submit( formData );     // Submit with AJAX, as usual
  } else {
    stack.push( formData ); // Push to stack! We're offline!
  }
}

// CHECK - Called when online
function stackCheck() {
  if (stack.length) {
    // Empty + submit the data in stack, one by one
    while (stack.length) submit( stack.shift() );
  }
}

// Listen for when online
window.addEventListener('online', stackCheck);
// Every form on our page
$('form').on('submit', preSubmit);
```

```html
<form action="/api/message" method="delete">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="31">
  <input type="submit" value="Delete message">
</form>

<form action="/api/user" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="john">
  <input type="text" name="surname" value="doe">
  <input type="submit" value="Add user">
</form>

Now, open developer console and check the "Offline" mode.<br>
Click the buttons and turn back online.

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

PS: worth reading and implementing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at local storage. You should be able to save the form data that you want and will need to check the POST/GET request status or utilize some other method to determine when the connection has resumed prior to sending the form data.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible via a service worker and the background sync web api, which became available in Chrome in March 2016.

For caching the post request locally, you can use either the localstorage api or the cache api.

Here's a tutorial from Google on using the background sync api: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync

To summarize:

1. You'll register a service worker:
   `navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js');`
2. Then you sync it with the client using `swRegistration.sync.register('myFirstSync');`
3. Then, inside the service worker listen for the sync event.
4. Inside the service worker's "sync" event listener you will write the code that pulls the post request data from local storage and makes the post request again.

Hope this helps!